# In fillna, what is the difference between pad and ffill method?

Tags: pandas

In `fillna`, the arguments `method='pad'` and `method='ffill'` appear to give the same behavior. Is there any difference?  Is one method preferable to the other?

Answer (score 11):

[pandas.DataFrame.fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

They are the same. I like `'ffill'` because it's more descriptive of what it does.

---

We can see in the source for the generic `NDFRame.fillna`
[source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/a00154dcfe5057cb3fd86653172e74b6893e337d/pandas/core/generic.py#L4273)

```
    method = missing.clean_fill_method(method)
```

Where we can see that when `method == 'ffill'` it gets swapped for `'pad'`
[source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/a00154dcfe5057cb3fd86653172e74b6893e337d/pandas/core/missing.py#L80-L81)

```
    if method == 'ffill':
        method = 'pad'
```

---

**Note**
pandas also has a [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) method that does the same thing

Comment: I even do not aware pad exist ..:-)